# Deep copy of properties one object to anothe from jackson?

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am performing an UPDATE operation such that all the `non-null` properties set in the incoming POJO shall be copied into another object (same type) and this shall happen for nested properties too.

Ex:

POJO:

```
    public class Person {

        private String homePhoneNumber;
        private String officePhoneNumber;

        private Address address;

        public String getHomePhoneNumber() {
            return homePhoneNumber;
        }

        // getter/setters


    }

    public class Address {

        private String street;
        private String houseNumber;

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }
        // getter/setters
    }

    //  Source

        Person sourcePerson = new Person();
        sourcePerson.setHomePhone("123");

        Address address1 = new Address();
        address1.setStreet("Street");

        sourcePerson.setAddress(address1);

    //Dest person

        Person destPerson = new Person();
        destPerson.setOfficePhone("456");
        destPerson.setHomePhone("123");

        Address address2 = new Address();
        address2.setStreet("Street2");
        address2.setHouseNumber("246");

        destPerson.setAddress(address2);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       //skip setters for null values
mapper.setDefaultSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.SKIP));

        Person result = mapper.updateValue(destPerson, sourcePerson);
```

So I want to copy all `non-null` properties set in `sourcePerson` to get copied in `destPerson` i.e **overriding** only those properties of `destperson` which `sourcePerson` has set, keeping other properties unchanged.

Using 
`Person result = mapper.updateValue(destPerson, sourcePerson);` 
is not working for nested properties. It's replacing the whole `Address` object from source to destination

I searched through jackson to find `merge` feature in jackson which:

```
mapper.setDefaultMergeable(true);
```

However, adding this configuration is making `null` values in `sourcePerson`  nullify those in `destPerson` too, which seems strange.

```
mapper.configOverride(Address.class).setMergeable(true);
```

This above configuration works for what I wanted. But I have many POJO nested resources, so I don't want specific configurations for each POJO.

Is this can be achieved with `jackson` in a clean way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by enabling error reporting with respect to *merging*

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature#IGNORE_MERGE_FOR_UNMERGEABLE

This needs to be false.

It's indeed strange that `mapper.configOverride()` sort of works, but not `mapper.setDefaultMergeable()`.

I don't see setters in your example. Aren't you using `@JsonSetter` annotations in `Person` class by any chance? Then they would override mapper configuration.

In *jackson-databind* Unit Tests I see they are using `mapper.readerForUpdating()` rather than `mapper.updateValue()`:

```
 private final ObjectMapper MAPPER = objectMapperBuilder()
            // 26-Oct-2016, tatu: Make sure we'll report merge problems by default
            .disable(MapperFeature.IGNORE_MERGE_FOR_UNMERGEABLE)
            .build();

    public void testBeanMergingWithNullDefault() throws Exception
    {
        // By default `null` should simply overwrite value
        ConfigDefault config = MAPPER.readerForUpdating(new ConfigDefault(5, 7))
                .readValue(aposToQuotes("{'loc':null}"));
        assertNotNull(config);
        assertNull(config.loc);

        // but it should be possible to override setting to, say, skip

        // First: via specific type override
        // important! We'll specify for value type to be merged
        ObjectMapper mapper = newObjectMapper();
        mapper.configOverride(AB.class)
            .setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.SKIP));
        config = mapper.readerForUpdating(new ConfigDefault(137, -3))
                .readValue(aposToQuotes("{'loc':null}"));
        assertNotNull(config.loc);
        assertEquals(137, config.loc.a);
        assertEquals(-3, config.loc.b);

        // Second: by global defaults
        mapper = newObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDefaultSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.SKIP));
        config = mapper.readerForUpdating(new ConfigDefault(12, 34))
                .readValue(aposToQuotes("{'loc':null}"));
        assertNotNull(config.loc);
        assertEquals(12, config.loc.a);
        assertEquals(34, config.loc.b);
    }
```

Also worth trying using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge` directly in `Person` class.

Comment: I can't edit my data model, so won't be able to annotate them. However, I tried `mapper.readerForUpdating(dest).readValue()` which works with `mapper.setDefaultMergeable(true)`; strange that it didn't work with `mapper.updateValue()`. In the end, I wanted my `List` to get replaced rather than merged, so added `mapper.configOverride(List.class).setMergeable(false);` for that

Comment: There's another requirement where I want to differentiate when the user set a property to `null` vs `default-value` is `null` for that property. Ex: A POJO with a BigInteger property set to `null` vs it's default value is also `null`. So can I do something while deserializing to differtainte that this one was set `null` by user and not by default ?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha Looking at `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers.BigIntegerDeserializer`, it seems default value set for empty _BigInteger_ is `BigInteger.ZERO`.
So maybe you can use null (which is different from ZERO) for the user set case.

Comment: Well, I don't see my `BigInteger` set to `0` by default, still it's not the only data type I have to take care of. There can any data type `List`, `Boolean`, etc where the user defined `null` and `default` `null` needs to be differentiated. I was thinking along the lines that just while deserializing some differentiation could be done ? Or you have a better solution ?